# Debug pointer is not working for maven project in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I have cloned the java-cucumber project and opened in IntelliJ, when I start doing debugging, I am not able to do it. I can set the break points but execution is not stopping at the debug pointer. I did go through many suggestions to fix it, but unable to do it. Below is my mvn run configutration.

Maven Run Configuration: clean install "-DTEST_SUITE=(@qa-31884 and @bh_smoke and @bhau_smoke and @2105)" -DDOMAIN_ENVIRONMENT=UAT -DTEST_THREADS=1 -DPROJECT=_2105

Also when I used DforkCount=0, I am getting error that DforkCount should not be set to 0, it should be >=1.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to share project example? Where do you put breakpoint?

Comment: I have put breakpoint in stepDefinition file. It is Java-selenium-cucumber maven project.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue on my side. Is it possible to provide project example?